# Cakephp File permission (Mac os)

Tags: file, cakephp, permissions, chmod

The Filelog.php has been chmod 777, but i still get the errors below. How can i fix it? Thanks.... (Mac os)

```
 failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/oven-master/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Log/Engine/FileLog.php

-rwxrwxrwx  1 daemon  admin  3068 Jul 27 09:49 BaseLog.php
-rwxrwxrwx  1 daemon  admin  3088 Jul 27 09:49 ConsoleLog.php
-rwxrwxrwx  1 daemon  admin  6370 Jul 27 09:49 FileLog.php
-rwxrwxrwx  1 daemon  admin  4570 Jul 27 09:49 SyslogLog.php
```

Comment: In all likelihood, you don't want to write `Filelog.php`, but the `logs` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should give permission in  `logs` and `tmp` those 2 directory `recursively`.

> May be those directory may not exist. Then you have to create in cakephp root and then give permission `recursively`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

how i solved it:
open terminal in your cakephp root project folder and type:

```
sudo bin/cake server
```